# QTableWidget hangs/pauses when not in focus

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I currently have a qtable widget that gets update 100s of times a sec. It seems to be working fine however I have noticed that after a while the updated values are not displayed until you move the scrollbar a little.Any suggestions on what might be causing that ?

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion: create your own model, based on QAbstractTableModel and emit dataChanged( QModelIndex(), QModelIndex() ); when your data is updated. That will force all visible items to be redrawn.